# How to remove Scrolling Space created by Image?

Tags: html, css

I added an image to my HTML and set the position to relative. Also, including new coords `bottom , right , z-index`, Even if the image location/position is in front of the body( overlapping it ) the scroll still extends to its ***Default*** location even if there is not space used. Is there a way to stop this?

A better explanation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXGg3.jpg

The Code :

```
.crow
{
  position: relative ;
  z-index:4;
  bottom: 950px;
  right: 502px;
  height: 900px;
  width: 1200px;
}

body
{ 
  font-family: "trebuchet ms", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .84em;
  color: #222;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-image: url(bruh.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: ;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  cursor: url(cursor1.png), pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to w3 schools

> ### position: relative;
>
> An element with position: relative; is positioned relative to its
> normal position.
>
> Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a
> relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from
> its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into
> any gap left by the element.

=> position relative does not remove the element from the page flow

> ### position: absolute;
>
> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the
> nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the
> viewport, like fixed).
>
> However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned
> ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page
> scrolling.

=> element is removed from the page flow

- [src](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.)
  you probably need to position with absolute

Comment: This solved the problem , i should pay more attention to the styles that i am using :D . It indeed removed the page flow , but the problem it causes now it's that the init-scale doesn't not work with the image anymore ,it remains behind